# Switching from Mint to Ubuntu will i be able to access other HDDs in my PC?

Tags: software-installation

After installing Ubuntu on my SSD will my new system be able to access my other hard disks and read the data in them. Previously running Linux Mint and the other HDDs are mounted on Media

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`/media/` contains external disks. All you need to do is not format them. After installing you will find them at the launcher and clicking them will mount them or plug them in to make them show up.

Comment: Thank You very much for taking the time to answer to my newbie question, took a load of my mind! Procceding with the intallation!